How do I monitor changes on entity properties in hiconic-js?
As I follow the MVC pattern in my application design, I want to react on an entity property change and update the corresponding field for this property.
How can I monitor such changes to react accordingly?

In order to monitor changes on entities, use the manipulation-model and the manipulation tracking feature of hiconic.js which is conventiently presented by ManagedGmSession. In order to do so, create your entities on the session. This form of creation will connect the entities to the manipulation tracking/notification of the session. The following example shows how to do that:
// create a session which will maintain entities and propagate manipulations on them to ManipulationListener
const session = new BasicManagedGmSession();

// create an instance of an entity via the session
const person = session.create(Person.T);

// implement a ManipulationListener. 
const monitor: ManipulationListener = {
  // In this example it will log the typesignature of a notified manipulation to the console
  onMan: m => console.log(m.EntityType().getTypeSignature());
};

// add the listener specifically for the given instance and the property
session.listeners().entityProperty(person, "name").add(monitor);

// changing a property will trigger the specific monitor
person.name = "Shiva"

